# Retorno Json - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

estou criando uma aplicação Asp.Net Web.API e o retorno do serviço é em Json.

Até ai tudo bem, acontece que o objeto principal (Empresas) esta retornando um objeto interno - cidadesFiliais (Filiais por Cidade) com um Colchete que não é interpretado corretamente pela View.

Na View já fiz um teste incluindo o objeto manualmente na página sem a inclusão do "[]" e desta forma ao invocar ***{{empresa.cidadesfiliais.cidade}}*** o nome de cada Cidade é exibida sem qualquer problema. Mas ao invocar o Json diretamente do BackEnd os registros para o objeto cidadesFiliais não são exibidos na tela.

Já sei que o unico problema é o "[]" interno conforme mencionado anteriormente, a pergunta é, como fazer para que o retorno do BackEnd seja igual ao 2º exemplo apresentado abaixo?

1º Exemplo - Forma atual do JSON:

{
  "empresa": "Industria Reunidas",
  "fonePrincipal": "3030-9999",
  "cidadesFiliais": ***[
    {
      "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
      "estado": "MG",
      "ddd": 31
    },
    {
      "cidade": "Salvador",
      "estado": "BA",
      "ddd": 71
    },
    {
      "cidade": "São Paulo",
      "estado": "SP",
      "ddd": 11
    }
  ]***
}

2º Exemplo - Forma como deveria ser gerado o JSON:

{
  "empresa": "Industria Reunidas",
  "fonePrincipal": "3030-9999",
  "cidadesFiliais":
    {
      "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
      "estado": "MG",
      "ddd": 31
    },
    {
      "cidade": "Salvador",
      "estado": "BA",
      "ddd": 71
    },
    {
      "cidade": "São Paulo",
      "estado": "SP",
      "ddd": 11
    }
}

Obrigado pela força!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu segundo JSON de exemplo é inválido. Utilize um *parser* como o http://json.parser.online.fr/ para testá-lo.

Os dois padrões em uso são os seguintes:

- Propriedade: `{"chave": "valor"}`
- Coleção: `["valor1", "valor2", "valor3"]`

O seu segundo exemplo tenta implementar um objeto onde as propriedades não tem chave, apenas valor.

Alternativamente você pode criar chaves *placeholder* usando o índice:

```
{
  "empresa": "Industria Reunidas",
  "fonePrincipal": "3030-9999",
  "cidadesFiliais": {
    "0": {
      "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
      "estado": "MG",
      "ddd": 31
    },
    "1": {
      "cidade": "Salvador",
      "estado": "BA",
      "ddd": 71
    },
    "2": {
      "cidade": "São Paulo",
      "estado": "SP",
      "ddd": 11
    }
  }
}
```

Note que isso faz com que a propriedade `CidadesFiliais` descreva não mais uma coleção, mas sim um objeto ondes as propriedades `0`, `1` e `2` tem como valor um objeto.

Na maioria dos modelos isso não é recomendável. O primeiro formato é o correto. Minha sugestão seria alterar sua view, e em vez de utilizar o formato `(chave, valor) in colecao` no seu `ng-repeat` utilize `item in colecao`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){

  $scope.valor = {
    "empresa":"Industria Reunidas",
    "fonePrincipal":"3030-9999",
    "cidadesFiliais":[
      {
        "cidade":"Belo Horizonte",
        "estado":"MG",
        "ddd":31
      },
      {
        "cidade":"Salvador",
        "estado":"BA",
        "ddd":71
      },
      {
        "cidade":"São Paulo",
        "estado":"SP",
        "ddd":11
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>

    {{valor.empresa}}<br/><br/>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>UF</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat='i in valor.cidadesFiliais'>
        <td>{{i.estado}}</td>
        <td>{{i.cidade}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ola OnoSendai, utilizei o primeiro exemplo (com chaves) no link http://json.parser.online.fr/ e o mesmo foi reconhecido sem nenhum problema! Será que o meu problema não esta no AngularJs, ou seja, quando um Objeto interno vier com "[]" devo utilizar alguma propriedade específica?

Comment: @urlflavio Apenas o segundo exemplo é inválido, o primeiro (gerado pela WebAPI) está correto. O Angular também está avaliando corretamente o objeto. A especificacão do JSON prevê as chaves como delimitadores de coleções (que é exatamente o que você quer expressar).

Comment: Ok OnoSendai, Se possivel, veja se estou fazendo algo errado:

Comment: Ok OnoSendai, Se possivel, veja se estou fazendo algo errado na View: Para apresentar o fone da empresa estou informando da seguinte forma ==> <td>{{empresa.fonePrincipal}}</td> neste caso o telefone é apresentado corretamente! mas para apresentar qualquer registro de "cidadesFiliais" o registro não é apresentado ficando o campo em branco ==> <td>{{empresa.cidadesFiliais.cidade}}</td>. Será que estou esuqcendo de algo? Voltei a utilizar o primeiro exemplo que é retornado da API.

Comment: @urlflavio Dê uma olhada no exemplo que incluí na resposta.

Comment: @urlflavio outra coisa - sendo uma coleção, `empresa.cidadesFiliais.cidade` irá falhar pois `cidadesFiliais` não possui uma propriedade chamada `cidade`. Entretanto você pode utilizar um índice: `empresa.cidadesFiliais[0].cidade` para o primeiro membro da coleção, por exemplo.

Comment: OnoSendai, show dw bola a resposta!!!! não querendo abusar... :) se fosse um objeto proveniente de um relacionamento OneToOne como que você faria esta atribuição, ou seja, como não haveria o "ng-repeat" qual a propriedade angular apropriada para este cenário? Muuuuito grato pela sua ajuda.

Comment: @urlflavio Sem problemas, é um prazer ajudar. =) Neste caso um relacionamento 1x1 pode ser expresso apenas como uma propriedade do objeto-pai.